# PHP - MySQL: How to allow the execution of a huge insert query with more than 40,000 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that creates a query based on a huge array

```
public function importFromCSV($uploaded_file) {
    set_time_limit(0);

    $arr = Utils::csvToAarray($uploaded_file["tmp_name"]);
    if(empty($arr)) {
        return false;
    }
    //Base query
    $query = "INSERT INTO ".$this->tablename." VALUES ";

    //var_dump($arr); exit; //DEBUG

    $i = 0;
    $totalRows = count($arr);
    foreach($arr as $row) {
        $r = array_values($row);
        //If title is not empty
        if(!empty($r[1])) {
            $query .= "(";
            $query .= "null,"; //Enables Auto Increment
            $query .= "'".$r[1]."',"; //Title
            $query .= "'".$r[0]."',"; //Referemce

            //Formats cost and price
            $rawCost = $r[4];
            $cost = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $rawCost);
            $rawPrice = $r[6];
            $price = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $rawPrice);
            $rawStock = $r[2];
            $stock = (int)preg_replace('/\D/', '', $rawStock);

            $query .= $cost.",";
            $query .= $price.",";
            $query .= "'".$r[3]."',";
            $query .= $stock;
            $query .= ")";

            //Separates each insert with a coma but only if it's not the last one
            if($i < $totalRows) {
                $query .=",";
            }
        } else {
            $totalRows--; //Removes the omitted row from the array count
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if($this->conn->query($query)) {
        echo "QUERY FINISHED";
    }
    exit;
}
```

The query it generates right now is huge. The array contains almost 40,000 rows.

The query is generated correctly. The issue is in the last lines of the function. Where you see the I call the method query (from the PDO class). If the query is successfully executed should echo "QUERY FINISHED" but it doesn't. I've tried to remove the time execution time limit but it doesn't work either.

If the query generated has 20, 30, 100 inserts it works properly and inserts all the data.

But when it has almost 40,000 inserts it just doesn't work. I don't mind it taking minutes executing as long as all the data is inserted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: create a temp file and use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: How many rows does it insert? Also, have you reviewed your Apache error log?

Comment: It does not insert any. When I get a normal array with some dozens of rows to insert, they insert perfectly. But when the query has 40,000 inserts it does not insert any of them. ------ And by the way, I'm also thinking about using LOAD DATA INFILE. Creating a new Temp CSV instead of a query.

Comment: I think you might've been hitting PHP's memory limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting it into inserts of 1,000 each

```
public function importFromCSV($uploaded_file) {
set_time_limit(0);

$arr = Utils::csvToAarray($uploaded_file["tmp_name"]);
if(empty($arr)) {
    return false;
}
//var_dump($arr); exit; //DEBUG

$i = 0;
$ii = 0;
$totalRows = count($arr);
foreach($arr as $row) {
    $r = array_values($row);
    //If title is not empty
    if(!empty($r[1])) {
        // new: Base query starts here
        if($ii == 0) $query = "INSERT INTO ".$this->tablename." VALUES ";
        $ii++;
        $query .= "(";
        $query .= "null,"; //Enables Auto Increment
        $query .= "'".$r[1]."',"; //Title
        $query .= "'".$r[0]."',"; //Referemce

        //Formats cost and price
        $rawCost = $r[4];
        $cost = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $rawCost);
        $rawPrice = $r[6];
        $price = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $rawPrice);
        $rawStock = $r[2];
        $stock = (int)preg_replace('/\D/', '', $rawStock);

        $query .= $cost.",";
        $query .= $price.",";
        $query .= "'".$r[3]."',";
        $query .= $stock;
        $query .= ")";

        //Separates each insert with a coma but only if it's not the last one
        if($i < $totalRows) {
            $query .=",";
        }
        if($ii % 1000 == 0){
            $this->conn->query($query); // insert the 1000 that have been put into the string
            $query = ""; //reset the string
            $ii=0; //reset counter so query can be built again
        }
    } else {
        $totalRows--; //Removes the omitted row from the array count
    }
    $i++;
}
if($this->conn->query($query)) {
    echo "QUERY FINISHED";
}
exit;
}
```

Because PDO::query is a "synchronous" call, the PHP must wait until the first insert has completed to move on to the next insert. This will put all the data into the database from the csv parsed line by line, but 1,000 at a time. Note I haven't tested this but the concept is clearly there.

Comment: Ok. I've tried this and it worked. I've made some minor changes:

1) I've divided it into 128 inserts instead of 1000. 2) I've had to make a change in the code so it removed the last coma of each query.

For the rest. It worked perfectly. Just took some seconds executing and all the rows are perfectly inserted.